# How to get Google Currency Converter back

Tags: google-search

This is  the currency converter and today I am not getting it on https://www.google.com/search?complete=0&q=1+usd+in+aed . Also I am getting a Search sidebar which I haven't seen for a long while too.

[image: google currency converter]

Search today:

[image: search today]

Comment: Works for me. What _are_ you getting?

Comment: added screenshot

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. Even your link works for me. I'm in the States. Perhaps this has something to do with your location?

Comment: try in incognito mode. It will reset your settings for that session.

Comment: It might have something to do with the search language and/or localization.

Comment: It works when I am logged out. If I log in, it breaks.

Comment: Reaching google.com from Canada is what breaks it. google.ca works. Proxying through the USA works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: the new results page requires JavaScript. If you accidentally disable it (I have Quick Javascript switcher) then you get the older one -- no weather reports, no currency converter, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

For me the capital letters of currencies does the trick. Also I have to be signed in my Chrome with my Google account.

```
EUR to USD
```